# Generate PHP breadcrumb array from YAML

Tags: php, arrays, yaml, breadcrumbs

I would like to create a PHP function that generate an array from a YAML file which describe a navigation menu.

Here is what I've done by using recursively:

**YAML**

```
main:
    - title: Accueil
      href: /
    - title: Who we are
      href: /who-we-are
      children:
          - title: About the team
            href: /about
    - title: Contact
      href: /contact
```

**PHP**

```
protected $breadcrumb = [];
protected $path; // For example : /about

public function getBreadcrumbArray($ymlArray) {
        
        foreach ($ymlArray as $key => $value) {
          
            if (is_array($value)) {
                array_push($this->breadcrumb, $value);
                $this->getBreadcrumbArray($value);  
            }
            else {
;                if ($key == "href" && $value == $this->path) {
                    array_push($this->breadcrumb, $value);
                    break;
                }
                if ($key == "href" && $value != $this->path) {
                    $this->breadcrumb = [];
                }
            }

        }
        
        return array_reverse($this->breadcrumb);
    }
```

**Result**

```
array(0) { }
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: So, `$ymlArray` already contains the parsed YAML data? How do you parse it?

Comment: I'm using a service that parse it for me, here it is : array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Accueil"
    ["href"]=>
    string(1) "/"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(10) "Who we are"
    ["href"]=>
    string(11) "/who-we-are"
    ["children"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(14) "About the team"
        ["href"]=>
        string(6) "/about"
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Contact"
    ["href"]=>
    string(8) "/contact"
  }
}

Comment: Well your array does not match your YAML file. the first obvious difference is that the `main` key is missing. If you preprocess your data after loading the YAML and your question is about how to process this preprocessed data, your question is not about YAML.

Comment: It's normal, main key is excluded from the result array...

Comment: From a YAML point of view (which is my view, and which is the view you are implying by tagging the question with `yaml`), it is *not* normal to exclude the `main` key.